# Returning all possible combinations of a python dictionary in a comprehensive way

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I want to return all possible key combinations of a python dictionary. 
In my case, it is a two-levels hierarchy dictionary.

My first attempt seems like a pseudo-code-like sequence of for loops. It works but it is ugly and it gets really painful if I have a lot of data.

I want a do the same task with the dict-comprehension approach.

Here is my attempt. Using this technique, I could easily end up with many - way too many - for loops.

```
dic = {
    'Sex' : {'Man' : 0, 'Woman' : 1}, 
    'Age group' : {'0-14yrs' : 0, '15-25yrs' : 1, '26-35yrs' : 2}
}

for x in range(len(list(dic['Sex'].keys()))):
    for y in range(len(list(dic['Age group'].keys()))):
        sex = list(dic['Sex'].keys())[x]
        age = list(dic['Age group'].keys())[y]
        print(sex,age)


Man 0-14yrs
Man 15-25yrs
Man 26-35yrs
Woman 0-14yrs
Woman 15-25yrs
Woman 26-35yrs
```

Comment: You are not creating any dictionary. Why dictionary-comprehension, then?

Answer (score 3):

I would use `itertools.product`.

```
for sex, age in itertools.product(dic['Sex'], dic['Age group']):
    print(sex, age)
```

`product` returns an generator of tuples, which you can do with what you like.

For an arbitrary `dict`, where you don't necessarily know the keys or their ordering in advance, I would tag each value with its key first.

```
>>> for t in list(itertools.product(*[[(k, v) for v in dic[k] ] for k in dic])):
...   print(t)
...
(('Age group', '15-25yrs'), ('Sex', 'Woman'))
(('Age group', '15-25yrs'), ('Sex', 'Man'))
(('Age group', '0-14yrs'), ('Sex', 'Woman'))
(('Age group', '0-14yrs'), ('Sex', 'Man'))
(('Age group', '26-35yrs'), ('Sex', 'Woman'))
(('Age group', '26-35yrs'), ('Sex', 'Man'))
```

Now you at least know the "type" of each value in the corresponding tuple; it doesn't depend on any specific ordering involving the original `dict`.

Comment: And to generalize this into a function without hard-coded keys, use `dic.values()` in `product`.

Comment: @Nathan The problem with doing that is you don't know the order in which the keys are used. (Unless you are in Python 3.7 and you know the original insertion order of the keys into `dict`, etc.)

Comment: Fair enough; I would either have the docstring say it's in insertion order (in newer Pythons) or, similar to your approach, you could return a list of dicts such as `{"Age group": "15-25yrs", "Sex": "Woman"}`. Returning dictionaries is probably nicer if you're worried about key ordering because then there isn't an ordering. And they can always do `tuple(dict.values())` if they prefer tuples. A `namedtuple` might be even nicer if the user only had keys that were valid as attributes, but that's a big assumption that doesn't hold here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your solution to be general as possible, you can do something like that:

```
from itertools import product
product(*dic.values())
```

That will give you a generator with the following values:

> [('Man', '0-14yrs'), ('Man', '15-25yrs'), ('Man', '26-35yrs'),
>   ('Woman', '0-14yrs'), ('Woman', '15-25yrs'), ('Woman', '26-35yrs')]

Comment: Depending on how `dic` was created and what version of Python you are using, you might also get `[('0-14yrs', 'Man'), ...]`.

Comment: Interesting, can you give an example for such a case, and what python version would produce such an output? Do you think OrderedDict(dic) would help here?

Comment: This is an example. Prior to Python 3.7, the order in which `dic.values()` returns the subdicts is arbitrary. In Python 3.7, it's guaranteed to be in the order in which the keys were first added to `dic`, but you don't necessarily know what that order is.